# JQuery Select All Option Values From DualListBox

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, listbox

I'm using a dual listbox plugin and am trying to select a list of countries using jQuery:

```
var countries = $('.selected').find(":selected").map(function(){ return this.value }).get().join(", ");
```

This is the listbox:

```
<select class="selected" style="height: 200px; width: 100%;" multiple="" name="countries[]">
<option style="padding:4px 0px 4px 8px;" value="CA" selected="">Canada</option>
<option style="padding:4px 0px 4px 8px;" value="FR" selected="">France</option>
<option style="padding:4px 0px 4px 8px;" value="DE" selected="">Germany</option>
<option style="padding:4px 0px 4px 8px;" value="NL" selected="">Netherlands</option>
<option style="padding:4px 0px 4px 8px;" value="UK" selected="">United Kingdom</option><option style="padding:4px 0px 4px 8px;" value="US" selected="">United States</option>
</select>
```

I'm trying to get a comma separated list that looks like this:

> **CA, FR, DE, NL, UK**

How do I write this JQuery line correctly?

**EDIT 1**

```
var countries = $('.selected').find('option').each(function(){return $(this).val();}).get().join(", ");
```

This produces:

> [object HTMLOptionElement], [object HTMLOptionElement], [object
>   HTMLOptionElement], [object HTMLOptionElement], [object
>   HTMLOptionElement], [object HTMLOptionElement]

So I think I am close?

Comment: I'm confused, doesn't it already give that? Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jbusperc/) Also, `selected` should just be `selected`, not `selected=""`

Comment: The problem is they aren't actually focussed/selected. This box is automatically generated by a plugin. I need to get the whole contents of this select box. A dual list box basically shuffles options between the two boxes. I can't rely on them being highlighted/selected from the user perspective.

Comment: They should be selected, but the box might not be focused. Can you use `$('.selected').focus();`?

Comment: tried implanting .focus() before .find() but no luck unfortunately...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var countries = $('.selected').find('option').map(function() { return this.value }).get().join(", ");
```